# how come this code does the scraping correctly but doesn't save any csv or excel files?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, saving-data

I took this code from the book "Machine learning for algorithmic trading". It's a code used for **scraping** the seaking alpha.com of quoted companies.
I see that the code does the scraping correctly, but then I can't see the saved file with the scraping results.
I think the paths might be wrong but I am not sure. I am using Macbook pro and Spider.
Thank you
Alessio

```py
__author__ = 'Stefan Jansen'

import re
from pathlib import Path
from random import random
from time import sleep
from urllib.parse import urljoin

import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from furl import furl
from selenium import webdriver

transcript_path = Path('transcripts')

def store_result(meta, participants, content):
    """Save parse content to csv"""
    path = transcript_path / 'parsed' / meta['symbol']
    if not path.exists():
        path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    pd.DataFrame(content, columns=['speaker', 'q&a', 'content']).to_csv('content.csv', index=False)
    pd.DataFrame(participants, columns=['type', 'name']).to_csv('participants.csv', index=False)
    pd.Series(meta).to_csv('earnings.csv')
    

def parse_html(html):
    """Main html parser function"""
    date_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})')
    quarter_pattern = re.compile(r'(\bQ\d\b)')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    meta, participants, content = {}, [], []
    h1 = soup.find('h1', itemprop='headline')
    if h1 is None:
        return
    h1 = h1.text
    meta['company'] = h1[:h1.find('(')].strip()
    meta['symbol'] = h1[h1.find('(') + 1:h1.find(')')]

    title = soup.find('div', class_='title')
    if title is None:
        return
    title = title.text
    print(title)
    match = date_pattern.search(title)
    if match:
        m, d, y = match.groups()
        meta['month'] = int(m)
        meta['day'] = int(d)
        meta['year'] = int(y)

    match = quarter_pattern.search(title)
    if match:
        meta['quarter'] = match.group(0)

    qa = 0
    speaker_types = ['Executives', 'Analysts']
    for header in [p.parent for p in soup.find_all('strong')]:
        text = header.text.strip()
        if text.lower().startswith('copyright'):
            continue
        elif text.lower().startswith('question-and'):
            qa = 1
            continue
        elif any([type in text for type in speaker_types]):
            for participant in header.find_next_siblings('p'):
                if participant.find('strong'):
                    break
                else:
                    participants.append([text, participant.text])
        else:
            p = []
            for participant in header.find_next_siblings('p'):
                if participant.find('strong'):
                    break
                else:
                    p.append(participant.text)
            content.append([header.text, qa, '\n'.join(p)])
    return meta, participants, content


SA_URL = 'https://seekingalpha.com/'
TRANSCRIPT = re.compile('Earnings Call Transcript')

next_page = True
page = 1
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/Users/alessiomontani/Documents/0_Python/CODE/Machine-Learning-for-Algorithmic-Trading-Second-Edition-master/03_alternative_data/02_earnings_calls copy/geckodriver')
while next_page:
    print(f'Page: {page}')
    url = f'{SA_URL}/earnings/earnings-call-transcripts/{page}'
    driver.get(urljoin(SA_URL, url))
    sleep(8 + (random() - .5) * 2)
    response = driver.page_source
    page += 1
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.find_all(name='a', string=TRANSCRIPT)
    if len(links) == 0:
        next_page = False
    else:
        for link in links:
            transcript_url = link.attrs.get('href')
            article_url = furl(urljoin(SA_URL, transcript_url)).add({'part': 'single'})
            driver.get(article_url.url)
            html = driver.page_source
            result = parse_html(html)
            if result is not None:
                meta, participants, content = result
                meta['link'] = link
                store_result(meta, participants, content)
                sleep(8 + (random() - .5) * 2)

driver.close()
#pd.Series(articles).to_csv('articles.csv')
```

Comment: > I can't see the saved file with the scraping results. Well that's because the line that saves results to csv is commented out. But also I can't say from the code what should be inside `articles`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. If I try to put '''pd.Series(articles).to_csv('articles.csv')''' I receive the error code 'Undefined name articles' and the code doesn't save any csv files from the website. How can I fix this?

Comment: Well yes that’s the point. Since articles is not defined, you can’t save it to Csv

Comment: You should have you data store by calling store result function

Comment: thanks, how can I do that? How can I call store result function?